# Parsing ASPX Pages with PHP FAST CGI Cannot Start Session

Tags: php, iis-7.5

Banding my head against a wall here.

I'm converting a C#.NET site running on IIS 7.5 (Windows Web Server Edition) from C#.NET to PHP 5.3.10.  Everything is done but the pages that the customer uses for their google Adwords account need to remain the same.  You can't redirect a google landing page.  In order to handle this I've removed all the aspx extension handlers and replaced with PHP FastCGI on all *.aspx extensions.  I've also placed the application in it's own app pool running in classic mode etc.

When the page loads it throws a cannot start session warning.  PHP itself works fine but the page seems to have passed something to the browser that is not allowing php to start a session, set cookies, or do a header redirect.

Anyway this isn't the first time I've done this so it should work.  Also it's not a whitespace issue.  I know how to start a session etc.  IIS is doing something when parsing these files and I'm not familiar enough to know where to look.

Ty in advance for all your help.

At my wits end.

Comment: If you add a php page with only `<?php session_start();` as content, does that fail loudly as well? Also, try `var_dump(headers_sent());` right before your calls to `session_start()`.

Comment: var_dump(headers_set()); gives me bool(true)

Comment: also this file <?php session_start(); ?> as test.aspx throws the standard two warnings unable to set cookie and unable to set cache.  The same file with a .php extension sets the session cookie and throw no error.  Also var_dump(headers_sent()); throw false.

Comment: Just for hahas if I turn output buffering to on in my php.ini file.  I can now get a session to start in my .aspx file.  What the heck would make 1 file extension behave differently than the other.  I've done a compare on php_info() produced from my test.aspx and test.php and they both produce exactly the same file to the white space.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be much easier to use the URL rewrite module to rewrite all requests for `.aspx` pages to `.php`?  Like this:

```
<rule name="Rewrite ASPX to PHP" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)\.aspx$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}.php" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```